# vala FileInfo get_file_type is UNKNOWN

Tags: glib, vala, gio

I've been trying to make a function that goes through a directory and lists all the files in the directory and any sub-directories:

```
void get_listing (string dir) {
    try {
        var directory = File.new_for_path (dir);

        var enumerator = directory.enumerate_children (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_NAME, 0);

        FileInfo file_info;
        while ((file_info = enumerator.next_file ()) != null) {
            stdout.printf(file_info.get_file_type().to_string());
            if (file_info.get_file_type() == FileType.DIRECTORY) {
                get_listing(file_info.get_name());
            } else {
                stdout.printf ("%s\n", file_info.get_name ());
            }
        }

    } catch (Error e) {
        stderr.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
        return;
    }
}
int main (string[] args) {
    get_listing(".");

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code none of the files in any sub-directories are outputted. All the files/directories types are "G_FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN". Does anyone know how to fix this or another method I could use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are enumerating files by name only; if you wish to access file type later, you should pass appropriate hint to enumerator:

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_NAME + "," + FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_TYPE
```